# Git whatchanged - how to see full path of a file with changes

Tags: git

I am trying to have list number of changes of files in a specific range (since .. until date) in a Git repository (Chromium) 
My command is:

```
git whatchanged --since="Aug 16 2009" --until="Aug 17 2009" --stat -r
```

Output is:

```
.../extensions/extension_browsertests_misc.cc      |    1 -
```

My problem is that I want to see the full path of the file, not with "..."

I tried something like:

```
git whatchanged --since="Aug 16 2009" --until="Aug 17 2009" --full-diff --abbrev=400
```

Result:

> :100644 100644 a3d3889fd542c60c98b6e1b2ecf0bc90148f20e8
>   81c723db7e83b1bcd7c5da8778c52ab164e569da
>   M chrome/browser/extensions/extension_browsertests_misc.cc

It's a 40-byte hexadecimal commit object name. I tried to convert this hex to decimal but the result was far different from "1 -" (want the same as above not-full-path result)

My question is:
Do you have any idea to use git whatchanged in order to show full path of a file with number of changes behind?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whatchanged can take the same commands as `diff-tree` and `rev-list` which it uses internally.  you can  try adding `--stat=200 --stat-name-width=150`  to your command from `diff-tree` which will adjust the width of the stats column to `200`, and the file name to `150` which should give you all of it, or you can use `--pretty` to adjust the log output to your needs in other ways

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation about "stat" argument with function "git whatchanged" and then I found it in "git log" man page: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html 
Still dont understand why we can use it in "git whatchanged" and why it's not written in "git whatchanged" man page.

Comment: Well Git (like most unix tool) is a series of small commands that all work together.  If you read the man page for whatchanged, you will see it is made up of git rev-list and git diff-tree, which it calls to produce its output. in the description of the man page you have `  The command internally invokes git rev-list piped to git diff-tree, and takes command line options for both of these commands.`  So if you look at the man pages for both of those, you will find a stat option on git diff-tree.  I am going to edit my answer to reflect it as diff-tree as opposed to log.